# react-native run-android fails -- cannot find Kotlin

Tags: react-native

**A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.**

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
>   Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>          - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom
>          - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.jar
>          - https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.pom
>          - https://maven.fabric.io/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.11.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :app > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0

This stacktrace tells me that react-native is looking for Kotlin JDK for some reason. Not sure why Kotlin would be required, when everything is in Java.

I have included `implementation org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11`
in my app build.gradle, exactly the same version as seen in the stack dump

app build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.recordit'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        minSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
        ]
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "**"
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-radial-gradient')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

and project build.gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version='1.1.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        // For non-detach
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/maven"
        }
        // For detach
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expokit/maven"
        }
        maven {
            // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
            url "$rootDir/maven-test"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC built for Android
            url "$rootDir/../home/node_modules/jsc-android/android"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
            // dirs project(':expoview').file('libs')
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        // Want this last so that we never end up with a stale cache
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: adding implementation is not enough and you have to add 'apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' at the bottom of app/build.gradle too. but the question still remains why it needs kotlin in the first place? react-native itself does not need kotlin. you better check your libraries

Comment: Please attach your root level and app level `build.gradle` files in the question